# Is a holomorphic function with nonvanishing derivative almost injective?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal-maps

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb C$, be an open, bounded, connected, contractible subset with smooth boundary.

Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb C$ be holomorphic, and suppose that its derivative $f'$ is everywhere non-vanishing.

> Is true that for almost every $y \in f(\Omega)$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is a singleton?

I guess that one could build a counter example by using $g \times g$, where $g: \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb S^1$ is given by $g(\theta)=2\theta$, but I am not sure.

Comment: Not sure about the question as if you take a large disc centered at zero, it will contain the $2\pi i$ translate of a smaller sub-disc and $e^z$ restricted to the big disc takes each value in the image of that sub-disc at least two times, image being open hence of positive measure

Comment: It is true for simplely connected domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample can be found by letting $f(z) = z^2$ and $f$ is defined on $\Omega$ which

- contains $\pm 1$,
- does not contain $0$, and
- is open, bounded, connected, contractible subset with smooth boundary.

There are open neighborhoods $U_\pm$ of $\pm 1$ in $\Omega$ such that
$$ f|_{U_\pm} :U_\pm \to f(U_\pm)$$
is a biholomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I thought of $z \to z^2$ but somehow didn't think to move out the origin. So you can just take $U^+$ to be a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $1$, and set $U^-=-U^+$, right?

Comment: @AsafShachar That's true.